# How to cast the index variable in a for-in loop in typescript?

Tags: typescript, loops, casting

I have an object like this:

```
const lettersAtIndex: {[index: string]: string[]} = {4: ['a', 'b'], 6: ['c', 'f']}
```

I would like to loop over it:

```
Object.keys(lettersAtIndex).forEach(index => {
    doSomething(lettersAtIndex[index]) // index expression is not of type number
    doSomething2(lettersAtIndex[index]) // index expression is not of type number
    doSomething3(lettersAtIndex[index]) // index expression is not of type number
})
```

What's the recommended way of casting `index` to a number. Should I just create another variable?

```
Object.keys(lettersAtIndex).forEach(index => {
    const numericIndex = Number(index)
    doSomething(lettersAtIndex[numericIndex])        
    doSomething2(lettersAtIndex[numericIndex])
    doSomething3(lettersAtIndex[numericIndex])
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like `Object.keys` does not have a template signature (`Object.keys<T>`). However, you can map the `string[]` returned from `Object.keys` to a `Number` constructor and then pass it along to `forEach`. Similar to what you suggested.

```
Object.keys(obj)
    .map(Number)
    .forEach(index => {
        // index is a number here
    });
```

Comment: I like it. Or just `Object.keys(obj).map(Number).forEach(...)`

Comment: Yes! That's it! Thanks @nachocab

Answer (score 1):

`Object.keys` always return a string, therefore, your way above is good.

But in your case, I think `index` has nothing to do with the functions, so why don't you use

```
Object.values(lettersAtIndex).forEach(val => {
    doSomething(val)        
    //...
})
```

If you need the index to be a number, and don't want to transform it, you can consider using `Map` as well

```
const lettersAtIndex = new Map<number, string[]>([[4, ['a', 'b']], [6, ['c', 'f']]]);

Array.from(lettersAtIndex.keys()).forEach((index) => {
    doSomething(lettersAtIndex[index]);
});
```